# Angular Quickstart - npm install issues

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I'm following the [getting started guide for Angular](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart).

So far I have cloned the repo and and am now trying `npm install` but am hitting errors:

```
npm WARN package.json angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/angular2/-/angular2-2.0.0-beta.1
4.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with statu
s code 404
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/systemjs/-/systemjs-0.19.25.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with statu
s code 404
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-4.10.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with statu
s code 404
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/chalk/-/chalk-0.5.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with statu
s code 404
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-2.6.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with statu
s code 404
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/meow/-/meow-3.3.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with statu
s code 404
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.11
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-adapter/-/socket.io-ad
apter-0.4.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with statu
s code 404
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
-
> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall C:\Users\rparker\Documents\GitHub\angula
r2-quickstart
> typings install

typings ERR! message Unable to read typings for "jasmine". You should check the
entry paths in "jasmine.d.ts" are up to date
typings ERR! caused by Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/D
efinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd/jasmine/
jasmine.d.ts"
typings ERR! caused by unable to get local issuer certificate

typings ERR! cwd C:\Users\rparker\Documents\GitHub\angular2-quickstart
typings ERR! system Windows_NT 6.1.7601
typings ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\rpa
rker\\Documents\\GitHub\\angular2-quickstart\\node_modules\\typings\\dist\\bin.j
s" "install"
typings ERR! node -v v4.4.1
typings ERR! typings -v 0.7.12

typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x8
6)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.20
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall: `typings install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall script 'typings ins
tall'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     typings install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rparker\Documents\GitHub\angular2-quickstart\npm-debug.log
```

For the resources it fails to download, I can get these fine by just opening the URLs in my browser. The same with the DefinitleyTyped lib that's giving the `unable to get local issuer certificate` error.

So I'm unsure what to do next.

I have tried adding the following to my .npmrc file:

```
ca=
strict-ssl=false
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

But this has made no difference, I'm running node v 4.4.1 in case that's relevant.

Has anyone faced any similar problems when trying to install the dependencies for this repo?

Comment: What type of system, windows MAC? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Hi @MarkPieszak - I'm on Windows 7, and I am actually behind a proxy in a corp environment. I have come across posts on how to add proxy settings to the .npmrc file using the `proxy` and `https-proxy` options, which I have tried after getting the proxy details from my support team, but I'm still no further in getting past these errors

Comment: You might have to talk with IT and tell them to allow access to npm and GitHub links via command line I think. I'm guessing they are denying all that :(

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the correct proxy address?

Check your npm settings:

```
npm config list
```

Some examples of what you might need:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set http-proxy http://username:password@ip:port
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@ip:port
npm set strict-ssl false
```

It might have changed lately and you need to try: http-proxy might be old

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.address:proxy.port
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark, I found out I had to add a .typingsrc file at the same level as my .npmrc file - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471669/encountering-an-error-during-npm-install-with-angular-2-quickstart-project